# Retornar os valores de uma array após determinada chave

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array com cerca de 100 posições dessa forma:

```
[
  {
      "1":{
         "id":1262,
         "nome":"Fulano",
         "sobrenome":"de Tal"
      }
  },
  {
      "2":{
         "id":1263,
         "nome":"Beltrano",
         "sobrenome":"da Silva"
      }
  },
...
]
```

Como faço para retornar todos os valores após a chave 2 ?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Quando você diz após a segunda chave você quer dizer a após a segunda posição?

Comment: Isso mesmo, após a segunda posição!

Comment: Amigo só para confirmar, você quer em js ou php?

Comment: Considerando a pergunta do @SilvioAndorinha, então não importa qual a chave dentro da segunda posição, você quer gerar outra array com os conteúdos a partir da terceira. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha É em php, desculpe a falta de informação!

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu não quero fazer outra array, eu quero imprimir os valores a partir da terceira posição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imprimir a partir da **chave** **3** sendo maior que **chave** **2**

```
<?php
$array = [
         ["1" => ["id"=>1262,"nome"=>"Fulano","sobrenome"=>"de Tal"]],
         ["2" => ["id"=>1263,"nome"=>"Beltrano","sobrenome"=>"da Silva"]],
         ["3" => ["id"=>1264,"nome"=>"Fulano 1","sobrenome"=>"de Tal1"]],
         ["4" => ["id"=>1267,"nome"=>"Fulano 2","sobrenome"=>"de Tal2"]]
         ];


foreach($array as $index => $value){
    foreach($value as $index1 => $value1){
        if ((int)$index1 > 2){
            echo "N&uacute;mero:".$index1.' '. $value1["id"].' '.$value1["nome"]. ' '. $value1["sobrenome"];
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, perfeito! Muito Obrigado @HarryPotter

Answer (score 1):

E se eu dissesse que você consegue filtrar essa matriz, sem iterá-la, pelo menos não da forma convencional?

Nada contra a solução apresentada mas deve-se evitar a todo custo loops aninhados. Isso é extremamente danoso para performance da Aplicação.

Traduzindo seu problema em partes menores, você quer localizar um determinado índice e retornar tudo depois dele.

Ao fazer isso, você está removendo alguns itens da matriz original, logo, você a está filtrando. E se você está filtrando um array, [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/array_filter) é a solução.

Você vai precisar de um *callback* personalizado haja vista não existir nenhuma função nativa pra fazer o que você precisa. A... "essência" desse *callback* será baseada na função [key()](http://www.php.net/key):

```
$filtered = array_filter(

    $array,

    function( $current ) {

        return ( key( $current ) > 2 );
    }
);
```

Isso produz:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1264
                    [nome] => Fulano 1
                    [sobrenome] => de Tal1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1267
                    [nome] => Fulano 2
                    [sobrenome] => de Tal2
                )

        )

)
```

> Nota: O foco da resposta é **filtrar** a matriz e não unidimensionalizá-la, tarefa secundária e posterior de extrema importância para manter a rotina longe dos loops aninhados.

Comment: Concordo. Além de ser uma melhor solução para a performasse, é de suma importância legibilidade do código.